# Server to send with some TCP Options

Tags: networking, tcp, scapy, tcpserver

I am trying to test something where it is required that the backend server(Apache) should have some TCP Options Set in its TCP Packet when it replies back.
In client side to achieve this I am using scapy where I craft a TCP packet to set the TCP options field in it.

Is there any way of doing the same for the server side?

Thanks in Advance,

Raghul Christus

Comment: 'Some TCP options' such as what? Thinking about it admittedly very quickly, I can't thing of any TCP options that you could set at the sender that could be detected by the receiver.

Comment: TCP Options like SACK, TimeStamp.. I need to make the server to send all the TCP Options.

Comment: How did you set options for your client, I have problem with setting SAckOk and Timestamp, you can find my detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234148/how-to-set-tcp-options-timestamp-and-sackok-via-scapy)